# what are the different ways to login and authenticate user (like using OAuth2 ,jwt ,okta ) in Django application

Tags: python, django, oauth-2.0, jwt, okta

I want to know what are the different ways by which live applications built on Django framework Authenticate users while login. what all ways are used apart from Django inbuilt authentication for user login .

I found all these tutorials using Django's inbuilt authentication from Django.contrib library.
I want to know what methods are used in real world live Django applications.